# Printing json array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to print a JSON array in a table. Here is my code. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "age": 10,
    "feedback": "feedback1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "age": 90,
    "feedback": "feedback2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "age": 30,
    "feedback": "feedback3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "age": 50,
    "feedback": "feedback4"
  }
]

var fileName = "";

function GridLibrary(fileName) {
  this.fileName = fileName;

}
GridLibrary.prototype = {
  set_fileName: function(fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  },
  get_fileName: function() {
    return this.fileName;
  }
};

GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: this.get_fileName(),
    error: function(that, e) {

      console.log(e);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // printing the keys
      var Mytable = "<table>";
      $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
        $('body').append('<tr><td id="div' + key + '" </td></tr>');
        $('#div' + key).append(key);
      });
      // printing the rest
      $.each(data, function(index, MyList) {
        $.each(MyList, function(key, value) {
          $('#div' + key).append(" " + MyList[key] + " ");
        });
      });
      Mytable += '</table>';
      $('body').append(Mytable);
    }
  });
};
```

the output is

```
 id 1 2 3 4
name name1 name2 name3 name4
age 10 90 30 50
feedback feedback1 feedback2 feedback3 feedback4
```

but I want it to be like

```
id  name  age  feedback
 1  name1  10  feedback1
 2  name2  90  feedback2
 3  name3  30  feedback3
 4  nanme4  50  feedback4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give this a try:

```
var table = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name1",
  "age": 10,
  "feedback": "feedback1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "name2",
  "age": 90,
  "feedback": "feedback2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "name3",
  "age": 30,
  "feedback": "feedback3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "name4",
  "age": 50,
  "feedback": "feedback4"
}];

function addTable(tableData) {

  var table = $('<table>');

  var tableHeading = $('<tr>');


  for (var title in tableData[0]){
    if (! tableData[0].hasOwnProperty(title))
        continue;

    var headingColumn = $('<th>'+ title +'</th>');
    headingColumn.appendTo(tableHeading);
  }

  tableHeading.appendTo(table);

  tableData.forEach((rowData)=>{

    var row  = $('<tr>');

    for (var columnData in rowData) {
      if (! rowData.hasOwnProperty(columnData))
        continue;

      var column = $('<td>' + rowData[columnData] + '</td>');

      column.appendTo(row);
    }

    row.appendTo(table);

  });

  table.appendTo('body');
}

addTable(table);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41g8g9Lc/1/

Be aware this doesn't check to ensure number of columns is same in each row. This kind of handling can be added if required.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like the the following, You can just replace the json array with your own:

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/OymgbN)

**HTML:**

```
<h2>An Example of Turning an Array of Objects into a Html Table</h2>

<div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
```

**CSS(Optional):**

```
body {
  background: gray;
}

#results,
#left,
#right {
  float: left;
}

#left {
  width: 33.33%;
}

#right {
  width: 33.3%;
}

#results {
  width: 33.33%;
}

h2{
  font-family:georgia;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: #f0ffff;
}

td,
th {
  border: black solid 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: georgia;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var json = [{

  "firstname": "Larry",
  "lastname": "Lane",
  "phone1": "111-111-1111"

}, {
  "firstname": "Gypsy",
  "lastname": "Lane",
  "phone1": "111-111-1111"

}];

//array to hold the html for the table
var html = [];

//add the opening table and tablebody tags
html.push("<table>\n<tbody>");


//begin adding the table headers

html.push("<tr>");

//loop through the property names of the first object
for(var propertyNames in json[0]){//begin for in loop

  html.push("<th>" + propertyNames  + "</td>");

}//end for in loop

html.push("</tr>");

//loop through the array of objects
json.forEach(function(item) { //begin forEach

  //add the opening table row tag
  html.push("<tr>");

  //loop though each of the objects properties
  for (var key in item) { //begin for in loop

    //append the table data containing the objects property value
    html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");

  } //end for in loop

  //add the closing table row tag
  html.push("</tr>");

}); //end forEach

//add the closing table and table body tags
html.push("<table>\n</tbody>");

//testing display of results
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
```

Comment: This code makes me cringe for two reasons. 1. js object keys are unordered, each row could have columns in a different order, if you always iterated on json[0] at least you would get a consistent order though not predictable. 2. Concatenating text and html (like: `"<td>" + item[key] + "</td>"`) leads to encoding problems and injection vulnerabilities. Since the question asks about jQuery, `$('<td>').text(item[key])` is a better suggestion than sending some down the (faster but buggy) array of string path.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new `<tr>` for each `<td>` while the keys and data points need to be on the same `<tr>`

add something like this:

```
   $('body').append('<tr id="keys"></tr>');
   $('body tr.keys').append('<td id="div' + key + '" </td>');
```

and then you'd need to make a new table row for each set of data points to append to the table, then loop through the data to create the `<td>`s.

Comment: Larry Lane's example gives the full code for what I mean, it should be easy to adapt for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different methodologies to output your markup.

If you're going to use string concatenation, use it for the entire table. The point is, you're appending the `<table></table>` body *after* you create the rows and cells.

Not only that, but repeatedly updating the markup on the page for every cell is simply poor practice and very non-performant.